# My Code has high complexity. How can I reduce it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm tryting to code a simple game called 'Atom'. It works really fine but I have a little problem. VisualStudio says that the first code below has a complexity of 10 and the 2nd one a complexity of 13. How can I reduce the complexity? Thank y'all in advance :)

```
checkForWin(){
    let winner = true;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.fieldSize; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < this.fieldSize; j++){
            if(this.htmlBoard[j][i].classList.contains("atom")){
                if(this.htmlBoard[j][i].classList.contains("suspectAtom")){
                    this.setField(j, i, "correct");
                }
                else{
                    this.setField(j, i, "wrong");
                    winner = false
                }    
            }
            else if(this.htmlBoard[j][i].classList.contains("suspectAtom")){
                if(!this.htmlBoard[j][i].classList.contains("atom")){
                    this.setField(j, i, "wrong");
                    winner = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return winner;
},



setBorder() {
for (let y = 0; y < this.fieldSize; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < this.fieldSize; x++) {
    if (
      x == y ||
      (x === 0 && y === this.fieldSize - 1) ||
      (y === 0 && x === this.fieldSize - 1)
    ) {
      continue;
    }
    if (
      y == 0 ||
      x == 0 ||
      y == this.fieldSize - 1 ||
      x == this.fieldSize - 1
    ) {
      this.board[x][y] = "borderField";
      this.htmlBoard[x][y].classList.add("borderField");
    }
  }
}
```

},

Comment: This may be better-suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are better ways to formulate the code, but there aren't any fundamental ways to avoid the cyclomatic complexity you have, I think, at least not without making the code more confusing than it needs to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reduce the complexity of the codes below?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64994445/how-can-i-reduce-the-complexity-of-the-codes-below)

Comment: This question is more appropriate for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange since it's working code and you'd like opinions on how to make it better. Please don't [repost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64994445/how-can-i-reduce-the-complexity-of-the-codes-below) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

One way to simplify would be by separating the iteration from the conditionals; Visual Studio Code's automatic refactoring will let you extract the function out very easily, so your `checkForWin` function could end up looking like

```js
checkForWin() {
    let winner = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.fieldSize; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < this.fieldSize; j++) {
        winner = this.checkForWinningCondition(j, i, winner);
      }
    }
    return winner;
  }
```

which now has a cyclomatic complexity of 4. (The extracted function would have an 8)

Another step you can take is to unroll some of those conditionals and see if we can eliminate any extra code. In this case, notice that the line `if(!this.htmlBoard[j][i].classList.contains("atom")){` is extraneous because it is already handled by the initial `if` statement; removing this will bring the extracted function down to a 7.

Performing the same refactoring approach on your 2nd function will yield similar results, and you should end up with a lower total complexity score

Comment: First of all thank you for trying to help me out but I don't really get the code. Maybe I should explain my game a bit: I do have a 5x5, 6x6 and a 7x7 Board which is randomly chosen after pressing 'Play'. There are 2-3 Atoms hidden in the field and the player has to guess their spot through guessing. Pretty much like 'Minesweeper'. And the Method checkForWin() should check if the player guessed right or not. If i use ur Code, it doesnt check if the Entries are correct or not :/

Comment: The code I posted was meant to be an illustration of the concept, not to be a drop in replacement. What part don't you understand?